# Filter operation via Stream and maintain as map instead of Stream

Tags: java, java-8

I am currently getting a map data from an external api call.

I want to ensure the data is not null or empty and perform a set of operations on it

by filtering to a specific key in the map and capturing results into another object.

The key itself is comma separated.

Example key / value in map.

```
"key1,key2,key3,id100" : {
     "val1: "",
     "val2: "",
     "val3: "",
     ... others
}
```

I am filtering to capture all values under this key (so data cal1, val2, val3 and others)
and then perform some operations.

But when I perform the filter as shown, I end up with a stream.

Thus Instead of just a **Map<String, Object>**, I end up with **Stream<Map.Entry<String, Object>>**.

Tried flatmap and getting following error:

> no instance(s) of type variable(s) U exist so that
> Stream<Entry<String, Object>> conforms to Optional

How could I convert it back to a Map from the Stream or a better way to filter this? Thanks.

Could have just done this via a for loop without Streams but trying to see how

I could achieve this in a Stream implementation thus not looking for a for loop solution. Please advice. Thanks.

```
private NewObject get() {

    Map<String, Object> data = // data filled in by an external rest call;

    return Optional.ofNullable(data)

        // using flatmap here throws above error
        .map(Map::entrySet)
        .map(entries -> entries.stream()
                .filter(entry -> entry.getKey().contains("id100))

        // I wish to carry on further operations from here by using the filtered map. 
        // having issues cos capturedData is a Stream 

        // even if using flatmap at this stage, capturedData is still a Stream.
        // wanting to do the following but can't due to it being a Stream and not a map 
        ).map(capturedData -> {
            Map<String, Object> at = (Map<String, Object>) capturedData;

            NewObject newObject = new NewObject();
            newObject.setName((String) at.get("val1"));

            return newObject;

        }).orElse(null);
}
```

Comment: To be honest, I'd just say `if (data == null) { return null; }` and not try to pipeline/nest the main logic.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- Fair enough. But would still like to stream it if not null though.

Comment: How are you handling when there are multiple entries with substring `id100` in the key? Return a list of `NewObject`s?

Comment: @user7 Based on contract with the external provider that would never happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `map` to construct the `NewObject` and use `findFirst` to get the first value (as per your comment, there will be only one entry whose key has substring `id100`). Finally use `flatMap` to unwrap the `Optional<NewObject>`.

```
return Optional.ofNullable(data)
    .map(Map::entrySet)
    .flatMap(entries -> entries.stream()
            .filter(entry -> entry.getKey().contains("id100"))
            .map(entry -> {
                NewObject newObject = new NewObject();
                Map<String, String> nestedMap = (Map<String, String>) entry.getValue();
                newObject.setName(nestedMap.get("val1"));
                return newObject;
            })
            .findFirst())
    .orElse(null);
```

Comment: Did you meant to place findFirst() above map(entry...  or is it intentional?

Answer (score 1):

This code below filters the entryset in `data`, collects it to a set before performing the next set of operations. `findFirst` is used so that there is only ever a single entry to deal with.

```java
Optional.ofNullable(data)
                .map(Map::entrySet)
                .map(entries -> 
                      entries
                        .stream()
                        .filter(e -> e.getKey().contains("id1000")).collect(Collectors.toSet()))
                .stream()
                .findFirst()
                .map(capturedData -> {
                    Map<String, Object> map = (Map<String, Object>) capturedData;
                    NewObject newObject = new NewObject();
                    newObject.setName((String) at.get("val1"));
                    return newObject;
                })
                .orElse(null);
```